# Form submission to different controller - Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my view:

```
<%= form_for @comment, :as => :post, :url => user_ticket_message_comments_path, :html => { :class => "add-comment", :id => "add-comment-" + @ticket.id.to_s } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :body, "Add comment" %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>
```

In my routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :tickets do
    resources :messages do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
end
```

I get a routing error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"comments"}`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are missing the user, ticket and message:

```
user_ticket_message_comments_path(@user, @ticket, @message)
```

You need those parameters, because the URL generated looks like this:

```
/users/:user_id/tickets/:ticket_id/messages/:message_id/comments
```

without the arguments, Rails doesn't know how to generate that URL.

Also, consider that the rule of thumb in Rails apps is that ["Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

[This post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) by Jamis Buck suggests that instead of arbitrarily nesting resources, you only use one level of nesting like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :tickets
end

resources :tickets do
  resources :messages
end

resources :messages do
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: How can I reflect this routing?  I feel like it's intuitive (user has tickets that have messages and comments)

Comment: @rabid_zombie see the changed answer

Comment: @psyho So I understand that the URLs are much shorter like this, but what if I wanted to reflect comments from a message from a User's ticket? e.g. user/:username/message/:message_id/comment/:comment_id

I feel like nesting it to get this routing is more intuitive.  What do you think?